# How can I find the class of an item and later unserialize it into an object?

Tags: c#

I am calling a method like this:

```
await App.CDB.InsertLogItem(logStart);
await App.CDB.InsertLogItem(logViews);
```

LogStart and LogViews are two classes that inherit from LogBase

Here's the method signature:

```
public async Task<bool> InsertLogItem(LogBase item) {
   await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, item);
}
```

For the case where there is no internet connectivity I am planning to store the value of item and then later replay it like this:

```
public InsertLogItem(LogBase item) {
   string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
   // store result as a string and possible somehow class name in a database row  
}

 public async Task<bool> InsertFromDatabase {
   string result = get result from database
   // get result and possible class from database and convert into item
   // this is the part that I am not sure how to do.
   return await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, item);
}
```

How can I convert result back to item here? I assume I need to know the class but how can I find the class?

Comment: Don't you have it as a parameter in the same method ?

Comment: Why not keep a var of the `LogBase` item you pass in, am I not understanding something here? Just create a private var of `LogBase`, then when you need to use it, you could type check it. for example: `if(_logBase is LogStart logStart)` etc vice versus... In general use `await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, (_item is LogStart ? _item as LogStart : _item as LogView)); - not sure about syntax

Comment: I updated the question slightly.  In the database row I can store anything such as the serialized string and a string for the class but I am just not sure how to do that with the given code.

Comment: @Alan2 this makes thing's a lot different with your last update.

Comment: Sorry,  I did add the comment in about storing in database but hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save both the serialized item as well as his type, you can deserialize, getting the type at run time.

Code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty0 { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass : BaseClass
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public static string SerializeBaseClass<T>(T item) where T : BaseClass
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var item = new TestClass { MyProperty0 = "11111", MyProperty1 = 1, MyProperty2 = "1111" };

    string serializedItem, serializedType;

    serializedType = item.GetType().FullName;
    serializedItem = SerializeBaseClass(item);

    Console.WriteLine(serializedType);
    Console.WriteLine(serializedItem);

    var deserializedType = Type.GetType(serializedType);
    var deserializedItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedItem, deserializedType);

    Console.WriteLine(deserializedItem.GetType().FullName);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Result:

```
Test001.Program+TestClass
{"MyProperty1":1,"MyProperty2":"1111","MyProperty0":"11111"}
Test001.Program+TestClass
```

As you can see, the object is deserialized to the correct type

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method generic and constrain the open type to something that is or derives from `LogBase`. Your Document should contain everything the original class had:

```
public async Task<bool> InsertLogItem<T>(T item) where T: LogBase 
{
   string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
   await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, item);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I will be storing result in a database and then doing the Create at a later time from the database. I will try to make the question clearer

Comment: If you only pass in `LogBase` then you will only be able to get `LogBase` out so I guess you have two problems.